# How to remove unused items from Android app's all file?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I built a simple flashlight app with just one switch and it worked fine. I decided to look what was in the apk generated, so I decompiled my app and after looking in each folder I found very unnecessary files in the res/ folder like **anim** , **values-sr**, **values-uk**, **values-ur**, **color**, **drawable-v21** and many more(around 90) which contained a 2 kB XML each. I don't use all this in my app as I have only one switch and all this unnecessary stuff increases my apk size and due to this Android Studio also generates lots of unnecessary entries in the R.java file. Can anyone help me to prevent all this from being generated in Android Studio, so that my apk becomes smaller in size.

**Edit :** Here is the gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.camera2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        resConfigs "en"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    sourceSets{
        res {
            resources{
                exclude {'**/drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17/*'}
                exclude 'drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17'
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug{
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files generated after de-compilation are by default for apps as those files are required by the app to run and display. If the Refactor method does not work, you can go in the *AndroidStudioProjects* folder, search for your app and manually delete files which are not required. You can add the following code to the `build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
// ...
resConfigs "en"
resConfigs "nodpi", "hdpi", "xhdpi"
}
```

You can also use `shrinkResources true` to reduce app size.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please send a screenshot of the files present after decompiling the apk. Files you mentioned like anim, values, color, drawable-v21 are present for any decompiled app.

Comment: Also a decompiled app file size is significantly greater than the actual app size.

Comment: Okay I understand what has happened. You might have added a new library, like Google Play Services which is adding its own resource files for additional languages. Check the edited answer. Also for reducing the app size you can see this. [link](https://cyrilmottier.com/2014/08/26/putting-your-apks-on-diet/)

Comment: The files which seem useless can be removed by `sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            exclude '**/drawable-ldrtl-hdpi/*'

        }
    }
}` in the gradle. Use it for the other files too. If this does not help, please attach your gradle file.

Comment: I posted another question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/44830220/7978130

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidStudio

> Refactor -> Remove Unused Resoursces -> Refactor

Comment: Done but still those files are present.