# Android Studio generating R-T-L resource files even when supportsRtl is set to false

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I have a simple flashlight app in which while debugging, I noticed that there are several RTL (Right to left) layout folders in the res folder of my apk. So I googled it and set **supportsRtl** attribute to false in my manifest file which was previously true. But even after this change the folders are still present. I have tried rebuilding the project or clean the project but of no use. The folders are named like **drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17** and others like **drawable-ldrtl-mdpi-v17** , xhdpi, xxhdpi etc. I am surprised at v-17 suffix because my min sdk version is 21. Also they contain files like  `abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png` which seems weird to me. Can someone please help me to prevent these files from being generated as they unnecessary increase my apk size. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Delete them if you don't want them.  Android Studio doesn't go in and delete already generated files, because it doesn't know if you plan on using them later.

Comment: If I could I hadn't posted this question. I cannot find these files using Android studio. They are only found in the apk and even if I delete them from the apk they still have references in the R.java file.

Comment: That particular drawable is part of the android support library.  So if you use the support library, it is part of your app.  You may be able to remove it via a proguard rule, but that's about it.

Comment: Well can you instruct me how to use proguard to remove it then??